# Copying tables data between different MySQL Servers

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

Imagine the setup of 5 myqsl servers and 1 of them has the correct data for some tables which are being updated all the time and I would like to copy over this data to the other mysql servers.

Now I do remember working on a MySQL Replication task once where through the same website I write to the Master DB and read from the Slave DB but in this case, is this possible to do? Also is it feasible to do?

An example of a table would be "Translations".  Whatever new translations are entered in one DB, they are copied to the other servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your own question.

You need to set up replication using master - slave servers.
Where you only do updates in the master and let the slaves feed on the master.

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html
http://crazytoon.com/2008/01/29/mysql-how-do-you-set-up-masterslave-replication-in-mysql-centos-rhel-fedora/

If you want a book I'd recommend: [High performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067).